# Ramda. anyPass with result instead of boolean

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have response of WordPress rest  api. Post can have featured image and it can be different sizes. I want to take large image. If it is not exist then medium and then small.

```
const data = {
  sizes: {
    small: {
      source: 's.jpg',
    },
    medium: {
      source: 'm.jpg',
    },
  }
};

const prioritizedSizes = ['large', 'medium', 'small'];
const possiblePaths = map((size) => path(['sizes', size, 'source']), sizes)
```

anyPass is "nearest" function I found, but it return just true if one of paths will be valid.

Also I found `either` function. Also good, but it takes only 2 arguments (if not first then second).

Any idea, how can I find first valid path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've changed a bit original `anyPass` and here is what I got:

```
import { curry, curryN, isNil, max, pluck, reduce } from 'ramda';

export const anyPassValue = curry(preds =>
  curryN(reduce(max, 0, pluck('length', preds)), (...args) => {
    let idx = 0;
    const len = preds.length;
    while (idx < len) {
      const callResult = preds[idx].apply(this, args);
      if (!isNil(callResult)) {
        return callResult;
      }
      idx += 1;
    }
    return undefined;
  }),
);
```

Example:

```
const sizes = ['large', 'medium', 'small'];
const possiblePaths = map(size => path(['media_details', 'sizes', size, 'source_url']), sizes);
anyPassValue(possiblePaths);
```

Comment: this is far from being declarative, it involves a lot of imperative control flows and mutations. I personally wouldn't go for it since it has also a `O(n^2)` complexity due to `while` being nested into a `reduce` function. Please, have a look at other approaches that don't require that.

Answer (score 1):

Extract all items in order from `sizes`, remove the missing elements (`undefined`), and if the 1st element is not `undefined`, take the `source`:

```js
const { pipe, propOr, prop, props, head, filter } = R

const getImage = prioritizedSizes => pipe(
  propOr({}, 'sizes'),
  props(prioritizedSizes), // get the ordered sizes
  filter(Boolean), // remove missing sizes (undefined items)
  head, // take the first element
  prop('source') // if found extract source
);

const prioritizedSizes = ['large', 'medium', 'small'];
const getImageBySize = getImage(prioritizedSizes);

const data = {"sizes":{"small":{"source":"s.jpg"},"medium":{"source":"m.jpg"}}};

console.log(getImageBySize(data));
console.log(getImageBySize({}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to clarify the usage of `anyPass` first. You can't use it to check the truthiness of a thing and return some information about it at the same time.

Let's take these examples: the predicate can return a non-boolean value but it will be casted into one by `anyPass`:

```
anyPass([always('foo')])([false]);
//=> true

anyPass([always('')])([true]);
//=> false
```

So you can't check if a path exist and return that path at the same time using `anyPass`.

Here's a solution involving [`chain`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain). *(Note that I'm not sure whether this is appropriate.)*

```
const findPath = data => {
  const large = ['sizes', 'large', 'source'];
  const medium = ['sizes', 'medium', 'source'];
  const small = ['sizes', 'small', 'source'];
  return hasPath(large, data) ? large :
    hasPath(medium, data) ? medium : small;
}

const findSize = chain(path, findPath);

findSize({
  sizes: {
    small: {
      source: 's.jpg',
    },
    medium: {
      source: 'm.jpg',
    },
  }
});
// m.jpg
```

`chain(path, findPath)(data)` is the same as `path(findPath(data), data)`.

Here's a solution using [`cond`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#cond):

```
// sizePath('large') => ["sizes", "large", "source"]
const sizePath = flip(insert(1))(['sizes', 'source']);
const hasSize = compose(hasPath, sizePath)
const getSize = compose(path, sizePath);

const findSize = cond([
  [hasSize('large'), getSize('large')],
  [hasSize('medium'), getSize('medium')],
  [hasSize('small'), getSize('small')],
]);

findSize({
  sizes: {
    small: {
      source: 's.jpg',
    },
    medium: {
      source: 'm.jpg',
    },
  }
});
// m.jpg
```

Here's a solution using [`ap`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#ap):

```
const size = compose(path, flip(insert(1))(['sizes', 'source']));

const findSize = compose(find(complement(isNil)), ap([size('large'), size('medium'), size('small')]), of);

findSize({
  sizes: {
    small: {
      source: 's.jpg',
    },
    medium: {
      source: 'm.jpg',
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have explained why `anyPass` won't do for you here.

I think the most straightforward version would use `find`, as you are trying to find the first match among the prioritized list.  Here is a fairly simple solution:

```js
const {find, has, __} = R

const firstSize = (priorities) => (data) => 
  data.sizes [find (has (__, data.sizes), priorities) ]

// ----------------------------------------

const data = {"sizes": {"medium": {"source": "m.jpg"}, "small": {"source": "s.jpg"}}}
const prioritizedSizes = ['large', 'medium', 'small'];

console.log(firstSize (prioritizedSizes) (data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

And if you only want the name (for example, `'medium'`) of the first match, you could use something even simpler:

```
(priorities) => (data) => find (has (__, data.sizes), priorities)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could write it recursively, 
something like the following `findImage`

1. take `size` from left (high priority)
2. traverse `data` until `size` or `null`
3. if found `return found`
4. `elseif length tail findImage(tail)`
5. `return null`

```js
const findImage = ([head, ...sizes]) => R.either(
  R.path(['sizes', head, 'source']),
  R.ifElse(
    R.always(sizes.length), 
    d => findImage(sizes)(d), 
    R.always(null),
  ),
);

const findBestImage = findImage(['large', 'medium', 'small']);

const data = {
  sizes: {
    small: {
      source: 's.jpg',
    },
    medium: {
      source: 'm.jpg',
    },
  }
};

// [Run code snippet]
console.log('best possible image is', findBestImage(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```